# C# Filtering List - More Than One Condition

Tags: c#, string, list, optimization, filter

I have a list of a custom data type called melter.

The two things in melter that concerns the filter is:

- Deleted
- Desc

I get/declare my list like this:

```
            // Return all the melters
        var melterslist = ServiceManager.ListStandingDataValues(StandingDataType.melters);

        var meltersActive = new List<IMelters>();

        foreach (var m in melterslist)
        {
            if (m.Deleted == false && m.desc.ToUpper().Contains(input))
            {
                meltersActive.Add(m);
            }
        }

        var json = new { MelterNames = new List<object>() };

        foreach (var m in meltersActive)
        {
            json.meltersNames.Add(
                    new
                    {
                        Name = m.Description,
                        Value = m.Id
                    }
                );
        }

        return json;
```

But i think doing to upper and contains is costing me to much processing time as the list size is > 1000.

Then converting it to a JSON every time i think is also killing it.

The JSON can be hit 3/4 times a minute as its use in a jQuery auto complete field.

Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this i.e LINQ query?

Thanks

Comment: are you after `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`? **Edit** or `meltersList.Where(m => !m.Deleted...`

Comment: Yes, in a sense but was more looking for advice on the whole string comparsion and converting to JSON best way to optimize

Comment: Sorry, hard to do examples without visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ, you can achieve this with:

```
meltersActive = (from melter in melterslist
                 where m.Deleted && m.desc.IndexOf(input, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
                 select new
                 {
                     Name = m.Description,
                     Value = m.Id
                 });
```

For the second condition (case-insensitive `Contains`), take a look to [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) and [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/435324/the-string-contains-method-should-include-a-signature-accepting-a-systen-stringcomparison-value).